# New Firebase cloud messaging server key keeps changing every week

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

The server key for cloud messaging under

```
Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging -> Server Key
```

keeps changing frequently, about once a week.

This is extremely frustrating. Our notification server calls fail with an error code of 401, which means it's an authorization problem.

But once I update the server key on my backend, with the key i see on the firebase console, which is different each time after this 401 authorization error, all works fine.

I have Googled my best on this, but there is no documentation, or support available for this error. Is this meant to change so much? If so, how can i update the SERVER_KEY automatically on my end..? Is there a REST API for this?

Comment: in firebase server key can't be change automatically check in backend whether key is changing manually ?

Comment: @barykaed key didnot change I have worked on several projects unless project is recreated or deleted

Comment: This is a strange behavior. I suggest contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked directly to the Firebase Support with an issue similar to the one you have and they told me:

> If someone changes the server API key in Google API console, the server API key will also be changed in Firebase console. ***Firebase does not change your server API key without notifying you***. Make sure no one has changed your server API key in Google API console recently and that the Server API key is the same in both the consoles.

A change in my API Key occurred only once in the time I have been using Firebase. So maybe you could contact the Firebase support or try to check if someone is changing the key in the Google API console.

Answer (score 0):

Google Firebase mostly sends you an email about upgrading their serve keys. when you receive such emails , quickly visit and update your scripts with your new key in the console. this can happen weekly or monthly, not really structured.